# backgroundworker stops work,return only error

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, kinect

I'm writing an application for kinect sdk 1.8 with c#. I'm using a method to know if handpointer is hovering an interface element, this metod run in skeletonframeready.

```
    public void CheckButton(Shape container, Point target, Point ContainerPoint)
    {
        // this allows our worker to report progress during work
        // bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        // what to do in the background thread
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            BackgroundWorker b = o as BackgroundWorker;

            _topBoundary = ContainerPoint.Y;
            _bottomBoundary = _topBoundary + container.Height;
            _leftBoundary = ContainerPoint.X;
            _rightBoundary = _leftBoundary + container.Width;

            //use midpoint of item (width or height divided by 2)
            _itemLeft = target.X;
            _itemTop = target.Y;

            if (_itemTop < _topBoundary || _bottomBoundary < _itemTop)
            {
                //Midpoint of target is outside of top or bottom
                args.Result = "no";
            }
            else if (_itemLeft < _leftBoundary || _rightBoundary < _itemLeft)
            {
                //Midpoint of target is outside of left or right
                args.Result = "no";
            }
            else
            {
                args.Result = "yes";
            }
        });

        // what to do when worker completes its task (notify the user)
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        delegate(object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Error != null)
            {
              // here the app stops
                Console.WriteLine(args.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                // Finally, handle the case where the operation  
                // succeeded.
                if (args.Result.ToString() == "yes")
                {
                   //Hovering
                }
                else
                {
                  //Not hovering
                }
            }
        });
        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

Until some hours ago this code works perfetly, now (without any modification) the code return always an error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it". What's wrong in this code?

EDIT

This is the calling of this method

```
 CheckButton(Rect, Point, PointLeftTop);
```

I call the method in main thread with a Shape, the handpointer coordinate as poin and the top left point of the shape. With those parameters i knoweach cycle of the app if my handpointer is hover a determinated shape,the same that i have passed as parameter. What i expect from this method is : call from main thread, dowork in background thread (bw.DoWork) , return result in main thread (bw.RunWorkerCompleted). 
The code stop here:

```
        if (args.Error != null){
         // here the app stops
           Console.WriteLine(args.Error.Message);
      }
```

Comment: Where in your code the error occurs?

Comment: I assume your backgroundworker invokes a method on the UI thread?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing there, but it doesn't look like background working type code.  It looks like UI work.

Comment: i edited the question, tell me if there are dubts